# Map already allocated memory into shared memory

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

If some memory is already allocated (for example using `malloc`), is it possible to then share that memory with another process, for example by marking the page as shared?

To be clear, this is distinct from initially allocating the memory as shared memory, for example using `shmget` and similar. Obviously it is possible to do this with `memcpy`, but is there a way to do it directly?

Comment: If this was possible, why would one need `shmget`? As it stands - I *think* the answer is no, since (to my understanding) shared memory is not stored on the heap.  But I'm not sure enough to turn that into an answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mmap() creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process.
The starting address for the new mapping is specified in addr.
The length argument specifies the length of the mapping.
```

So I imagine:

- Open a file in donor process for writing.
- mmap() your existing malloc'd memory.
- Open same file in another process.
- Enjoy shared memory.

Comment: However, that [same man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) immediately goes onto say the following:


`If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to create the mapping; this is the most portable method of creating a new mapping. If addr is not NULL, then the kernel takes it as a hint about where to place the mapping; on Linux, the mapping will be created at a nearby page boundary. The address of the new mapping is returned as the result of the call.`

Comment: @Jeremy Your mileage may vary, CPU can only share memory on per page basis anyway.